# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple with sys import in python

Tags: python, arrays

When reading in data, Python gives me the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple with sys
>   import in python

I use the following data.txt inputfile:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0
4.0 5.0 6.0
```

With the command !python file_name data.txt
    import sys

```
fp = open(sys.argv[1],"r+")
coordinates = fp.readlines()
fp.close()

import numpy

a = numpy.array(coordinates[0, 1, 2])
b = numpy.array(coordinates[3, 4, 5])

dist_unround=numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
dist_round=round(dist_unround, 2)

energy_unround=0.5*2*((dist_unround-3.0)**2)
energy_round=round(energy_unround,2)

print("dist \t energy")
print(dist_round,"\t" ,energy_round)
```

I try to calculate a vector from a random input textfile. Is there something wrong with my numpy.array code?

Comment: `coordinates` is a list of strings.  What is `coordinates[0, 1, 2]` supposed to do?  That's not how you index a list.  When reporting an error you should indicate the line where it occurred.  I have made an educated guess about that.

Comment: @Kevin Vlaar How did it go? Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @matisetorm I solved the problem by splitting the string between (' '), making a float of the input and cutting it in 2 strings of 3 values.

Comment: @KevinVlaar Cool. Glad you got it working. Is there something I could do to improve my answer to mirror your final solution?

Comment: @matisetorm My question was a bit short, so I did not mention exactly what I wanted, but you're answer did make it clear for me. Only I still wanted to use the data.txt file so I could not make full use of your answer.

Comment: @KevinVlaar well if there is anything I can do to edit so that the answer can be accepted. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

coordinates is a list, and you are you are trying to pass in a tuple `0, 1 ,2` on the `a=` line

To use method correctly, replace

```
a = numpy.array(coordinates[0, 1, 2])
b = numpy.array(coordinates[3, 4, 5])
```

with

```
a = numpy.array(coordinates[0].split())
b = numpy.array(coordinates[1].split())
```

Note that `readlines` returns a list of strings. Call index 0 on that list (`coordinates[0]`) to get the first set (row) of values, then use `.split()` method on that string to make them a list of strings that were separated by spaces.

You may want to cast those as floats or ints while you are at it. Could do that with a list comprehension if you wanted

```
a = numpy.array([int(x) for x in coordinates[0].split()])
b = numpy.array([int(x) for x in coordinates[1].split()])
```

Answer (score -1):

From the little details you gave, I guess, this is what you were looking for-

```
arr=[]
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a=list(line.split(" "))
        for element in a:
            arr.append(float(element.rstrip()))
print(arr)
```